# Blank page with in Angular app due to Cloud9 c9.live.proxy cookie

Tags: node.js, angularjs, cloud9-ide

I've got a nodejs / angular app that occasionally gives me a blank page when I load it, along with $injector:modulerr errors in the console.

If I open my Chrome resources, I can locate and delete the 'c9.live.proxy' cookie, refresh the page, and everything loads fine. Then, a little while later, either due to time duration or perhaps changing something in the app, I'll get the blank page again. If I delete the cookie, I'm good to go.

Has anyone seen this?

Answer (score 0):

Just wild guessing here, it might have something to do with the live updating of HTML/CSS that cloud9 facilitates. Can you open the page in the preview panel, then press the gear icon and tick 'Disable live preview selection'.

Comment: Thanks Jan, it turns out it was a problem with my grunt/bower build configuration.